# How to spawn_link a function on elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to do [this](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html#distributed-tasks) guide of elixir distributed tasks but I am running in troubles with this exception:

```
** (EXIT from #PID<0.62.0>) an exception was raised:
    ** (BadFunctionError) expected a function, got: #Function<20.50752066/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
        :erlang.apply/2
```

And after that raise this one:

```
[error] Error in process #PID<8796.100.0> on node :"silver@192.168.0.25" with exit value:
{{:badfun, #Function<20.50752066/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>},
 [{:erlang, :apply, 2, []}]}
```

I start `machine one` with: `iex --name gold@192.168.0.20 --cookie foo` and run:

```
iex(gold@192.168.0.20)1> defmodule Hello do
iex(gold@192.168.0.20)1>   def world, do: IO.puts "hello world"
iex(gold@192.168.0.20)1> end
```

Then start `machine two` with: `iex --name silver@192.168.0.25 --cookie foo`
And try to spawn `Hello.world` function:

`Node.spawn_link :"silver@192.168.0.25", fn -> Hello.world end`

After this, the error is displayed.

#### MORE INFO:

On `machine one` `Node.list` returns `[:"silver@192.168.0.25"]`

On `machine two` `Node.list` returns `[:"gold@192.168.0.20"]`

`epmd -names` on `machine one` returns:

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name gold at port 37295
```

`epmd -names` on `machine two` returns:

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name gold at port 39738
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally find the answer:

> You need to guarantee they are running exactly the same Erlang version. For production, we typically compile our code in a single machine and distribute it across, to guarantee the same version everywhere.

If you cannot guarantee the same version, then you must avoid anonymous function and always used named versions, such as:

```
Node.spawn_link :"silver@192.168.0.25", &Hello.world/0
Node.spawn_link :"silver@192.168.0.25", Hello, :world, []
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured out that passing named function worked. But was not sure why anonymous function didn't. Thanks for the info!

Comment: That is becaouse an anonimous function dosen't guarantees that you will have the same code on the other side.
i.e.: you have Hello.world/0 in one node implemented different than in the other. Vote me if you like my answer!

Comment: I suspect if has more to do with serializing the AST for the function. The function is converted to its binary representation (with :erlang.term_to_binary) send over the wire to the far end. The far end then converts it back to erlang terms (with :erlang.binary_to_term). It would make sense that different versions could have incompatibilities. With a named function, you are just passing module, name, arity across and not AST.

Comment: I found this to be an interesting read http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html

Comment: This solved my problem (had OTP 21 on one machine, OTP 18 on the other)

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is a problem with your example. You say

```
I start machine one with: iex --name gold@192.168.0.20 --cookie foo and run:

iex(silver@192.168.0.25)1> defmodule Hello do
iex(silver@192.168.0.25)1>   def world, do: IO.puts "hello world"
iex(silver@192.168.0.25)1> end
```

The iex session is on silver which you later start.

Additionally, the epmd list does not show an entry for silver@192.168.0.25 which you wrote the Hello module.

I tried this on two iex sessions on the same machine and it works fine.

Here are the steps you should take:

1. Bring up first iex session with a name and the IP address that machine
2. Bring up the second iex section with a name and the IP address of its machine
3. On one of the iex sessions type `Node.connect :"name@ipaddress" of the other machine
4. Define your Hello module on one machine
5. Do the spawn_link on the other machine.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the correct answer. I was asking about running in two *differents* machines.